# Kafka not distributing data among partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a topic with 3 partitions which gets 1.5 GB of data published per minute, but all the records end up in one partition (0), and the other 2 partitions (1,2) are not getting any.

I believe Kafka by default takes care of distributing data between brokers and partitions.

I would like to have data distributed among partitions so that I can scale up the consumer application by having more than one consumer instance in a consumer group. Since currently data is available in one partition, I'm unable to scale the application to more than one instance.

Please help out with your thoughts.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: share your code, especially message key generation.

Comment: I just have a topic name and consumer group using which I am reading data from topic but I find all data in one partition though it has 3 partitions. Producer gateway was maintained by other group, I am not sure what info you are looking for message key. Can you please add some more information to get clarity.

Comment: Maybe whoever is producing to that topic is deliberately or accidentally inducing this behavior. They might have written a custom Partitioner that ends up producing to one partition or they might be stating the partition number on ProducerRecord.

Comment: Or maybe they are simply producing all messages with the same key. You could easily inspect this situation by printing the key when consuming from that specific topic.

Comment: You cannot fix this as a consumer. Again, please share the producer code